# BLE Omron BP Monitor has it's Custom Service and Characteristics

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to connect with an Omron HEM-7140T1 BLE BP Monitor device. Problem is that this device doesn't offer standard BP service "1810" but offers it's custom Service and Profile . Service UUID - "FE4A".

How do I connect with this and get the readings and records for BP monitor from this device. Can anyone help please.

I tried using the nrf connect also but it uses it's custom Services and UUIDs only and not standard ones marked in Bluetooth documentation.

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer/retailer for help?

Comment: @Risto I tried contacting them but no revert, it has been 3 days

Comment: If it doesn't use the standard service then you either need information from the manufacturer or you will need to reverse engineer their protocol.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried, just now stuck with the decoding :)

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? Do we have to send some data to them first or something? (Write)

Comment: @SivasankaranKB No success yet man. If you every get anything in this Kindly let me know too